# AWS Lambda with Python write to CloudWatch throw DataAlreadyAcceptedException

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi I am building a AWS lambda function with API Gateway to write the log from ngx-logger in my Angular project to CloudWatch. Here is the python lambda function

```
def log(event, context):
    log_streams = logs.describe_log_streams(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP)
    nextSequenceToken=log_streams['logStreams'][0]['uploadSequenceToken']

    timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    result = logs.put_log_events(
        logGroupName=LOG_GROUP,
        logStreamName=LOG_STREAM,
        logEvents=[
            {
                'timestamp': timestamp,
                'message': Hello world, here is our first log message!'
            }
        ],
        sequenceToken=nextSequenceToken)

    return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

However, when I trigger my frontend with a few errors, I can see some errors are logged while some errors are not with the following exception

```
DataAlreadyAcceptedException: An error occurred (DataAlreadyAcceptedException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given batch of log events has already been accepted. The next batch can be sent with sequenceToken: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am thing if it is because Lambda is async and two requests get the same next sequence number. Is there any way I can avoid this issue? Thank you

Comment: Sequence token should be optional (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html). Is there a reason that you need to specify it?

Comment: Hi Ming, I saw this statement in the document you attached. `You must include the sequence token obtained from the response of the previous call. An upload in a newly created log stream does not require a sequence token. `. My understanding is if the log stream is newly created, then I do not need to set this value. But if I reuse an existing stream, this field is necessary. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is if the log stream is newly created, then I do not need to set this value. But if I reuse an existing stream, this field is necessary. Please correct me if I am wrong.

You are absolutely correct, and I apologize that I did not more closely read the spec.

Here's a quick example I threw together to demo how I would solve this problem. It's certainly not foolproof depending on the volume you expect to be working with. (Pardon the solution being in JavaScript rather than Python; this is what I'm more familiar with.)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    const LOG_GROUP_NAME = 'test-logs';
    const LOG_STREAM_NAME = 'test-stream';

    let nextSequenceToken = null;

    // Naive initial usage. Since we're including an empty nextSequenceToken
    // we'll call describeLogStreams first to retrieve the token
    nextSequenceToken = await log(
        LOG_GROUP_NAME,
        LOG_STREAM_NAME,
        'log 1', 
        nextSequenceToken,
    );

    // This is the happy path. It will still fail on the first log attempt if
    // another process has written to the stream. Note that we intentionally
    // don't update nextSequenceToken
    await log(
        LOG_GROUP_NAME,
        LOG_STREAM_NAME,
        'log 2', 
        nextSequenceToken,
    );

    // This will definitely fail on the first attempt since we didn't update
    // nextSequenceToken above -- but the first retry will succeed
    await log(
        LOG_GROUP_NAME,
        LOG_STREAM_NAME,
        'log 3', 
        nextSequenceToken,
    );

    return {};
};

const log = async(
    logGroupName,
    logStreamName,
    message,
    sequenceToken = null,
    retries = 3,
) => {
    if (sequenceToken == null) {
        sequenceToken = await retrieveNextSequenceToken(
            logGroupName,
            logStreamName,
        );
    }

    var params = {
        logEvents: [{
            message,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
        }],
        logGroupName,
        logStreamName,
        sequenceToken,
    };

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudwatchlogs.putLogEvents(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                if (
                    retries > 0 &&
                    err.code === 'InvalidSequenceTokenException'
                ) {
                    console.log('invalid sequence token, retrying');
                    const nextSequenceToken =
                        /sequenceToken is: (.*)/.exec(err.message)[1];
                    console.log('nextSequenceToken: ' + nextSequenceToken);
                    log(
                        logGroupName,
                        logStreamName,
                        message,
                        nextSequenceToken,
                        retries - 1,
                    ).then(resolve).catch(reject);
                }
                else {
                    reject(err);
                }
            }
            else {
                resolve(data.nextSequenceToken);
            }
        });
    });
};

const retrieveNextSequenceToken = async(logGroupName, logStreamName) => {
    const params = {
        logGroupName,
        descending: true,
        limit: 1,
        logStreamNamePrefix: logStreamName,
        orderBy: 'LogStreamName',
    };

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudwatchlogs.describeLogStreams(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data.logStreams[0].uploadSequenceToken);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Execution logs:

```
START RequestId: 64c93ac7-d7a3-415d-a65f-88f9a01f5e31 Version: $LATEST
2020-05-30T00:26:47.987Z    64c93ac7-d7a3-415d-a65f-88f9a01f5e31    INFO    invalid sequence token, retrying
2020-05-30T00:26:48.025Z    64c93ac7-d7a3-415d-a65f-88f9a01f5e31    INFO    nextSequenceToken: 49605487572640549775784175775008805339581397298215084354
END RequestId: 64c93ac7-d7a3-415d-a65f-88f9a01f5e31
```

This is kind of a hack -- and even AWS doesn't try to do this when working with potentially concurrent data streams (look at how Lambda executions create new streams for each underlying runner). If there is not a strong reason for you needing to send logs to the same stream I would suggest following a similar pattern.